# Reverse for 'form_detail' not found. 'form_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I'm trying to redirect to another view that goes to a randomly generated URL but Django can't doesn't know what to render.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my URL's in this one. I think I did it correct, but Django disagrees. What am I doing wrong?

> Reverse for 'form_detail' not found. 'form_detail' is not a valid view
>   function or pattern name.

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    randomUrl = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return redirect("form_detail", random_url=randomUrl)


def form_detail(request, random_url):
    template = "faq.html"
    context = {}
    form_detail = random_url
    context["form_detail"] = form_detail
    stripeUID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    payment = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://myUrl.com/accepted",
  cancel_url="https://myUrl.com/cancel",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  client_reference_id= stripeUID,
  line_items=[
    {
      "amount": 2000242,
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Expensive item",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  ]
)   
    context = payment.id
    return render(request, template, context)
```

App urls.py

```
from . import views
app_name = 'request'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('form-detail/(?P<random_url>[-\w]+)/$', views.form_detail, name="form_detail")
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you're inside an app.urls not in the principal project.urls
Which means you need to provide a namespace for the app.urls let's call it 'request'
So you need to use 'request:form_detail'

Comment: That was a simple fix. Thank you!